# Reload the total when removing a function - HTML & JS based form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

Once a row/field has been added, the function below allows a delete link to appear, and if clicked it will remove the row/field:

```
var ct = 1;
function new_bank(){
 ct++;
 var div1 = document.createElement('div');
 div1.id = ct;

 // bank to delete extended form elements

  var delLink = '<div style="text-align:right;margin-right:73px"><a 
  href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')">Delete</a></div>';
  div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newbanktpl').innerHTML + delLink;
  document.getElementById('newbank').appendChild(div1);
}
```

function to delete the newly added set of elements

```
function delIt(eleId){
  d = document;
  var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
  var parentEle = d.getElementById('newbank');
  parentEle.removeChild(ele);
}
```

The above code works correct. However as I have another Function which calculates the sum of the fields, and if I delete a row/field this sum doesn't update.

I am looking for a reload function when delete link is clicked or something similar, then refresh the Total function and update the Total to the correct amount

Below is my code for the total function:

```
//Creating total
function findTotal(){
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('Value[]');
  var tot=0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
   tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);}  
   document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `delIt()` function call the  `findTotal()` function again like below:-

```
function delIt(eleId)
{
    d = document;
    var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
    var parentEle = d.getElementById('newbank');
    parentEle.removeChild(ele);
    findTotal(); //call here
}
```

Now after removal it will recalculate the data and paste the new value to the `total` field.

Comment: @cos  please ask a new question and don't forget to add your efforts as you did in this question, you will forsure get an answer. Sorry  I am not that much familier with PDF creation.

Comment: Appologies. I didn't know you can only like one answer. as you answered first I will likes yours back!

Comment: @Cos  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to refresh the page. You can update the total by recalculating it after deleting a item; For achieve this, You need to change delIt() like this:

```
function delIt(eleId) {
     d = document; 
     var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
     var parentEle = d.getElementById('newbank');
     parentEle.removeChild(ele); 
     findTotal();
}
```